# Animate gradient background

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I am trying to animate my gradient but I am not able to get it to work. What am I missing here? I've read many different guides but it just wont work. I manage to get other animations to work, like rotate.

```
        public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {

        base.ViewDidLoad();

        CGColor[] colors = new CGColor[] {
            new UIColor(red: 0.05f, green:0.44f, blue:0.73f, alpha:1.0f).CGColor,
            new UIColor(red: 45/255, green: 128 / 255, blue: 153 / 255, alpha: 0.01f ).CGColor
        };

        CAGradientLayer gradientLayer = new CAGradientLayer();
        gradientLayer.Frame = this.View.Bounds;
        gradientLayer.Colors = colors;

        var animat = CABasicAnimation.FromKeyPath("colors");
        animat.From = NSObject.FromObject(colors);
        animat.To = NSObject.FromObject(new CGColor[] {
            new UIColor(red:244/255, green: 88/255, blue: 53/255, alpha:1.0f).CGColor,
            new UIColor(red:196/255, green: 70/255, blue: 107/255, alpha: 0.01f ).CGColor
        });
        animat.Duration = 10;
        animat.FillMode = CAFillMode.Forwards;
        animat.RemovedOnCompletion = false;
        animat.TimingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction.FromName(CAMediaTimingFunction.Linear);
        gradientLayer.AddAnimation(animat, "animateGradient");

        this.View.Layer.InsertSublayer(gradientLayer, 0); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should modify the `From` and `To` properties with `NSArray` like:

```
animat.From = NSArray.FromObjects(colors);
animat.To = NSArray.FromObjects(new CGColor[] {
    new UIColor(red:244/255, green: 88/255, blue: 53/255, alpha:1.0f).CGColor,
    new UIColor(red:196/255, green: 70/255, blue: 107/255, alpha: 0.01f ).CGColor
});
```